# Using binary search and user input

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm trying to figure out how to use binary search on a list that was already sorted so I can have the user search for a name that was entered by the user and have it display the name if it's there or tell the user if it's not.

I cannot use built-in sort functions.

I have the bubble search setup to sort the list of names entered by the user, which is the code below:

```
def names():
  members = []
  done = False
  while done != True:
    mem = input("Enter a name, enter 'done' when finished: ")
    if mem == "done":
      done = True
    else:
      members.append(mem)
    print(members)

    index = len(members) - 1
    sort = False

    while not sort:
        sort = True
        for j in range(0, index):
            if members[j] > members[j + 1]:
                sort = False
                members[j], members[j + 1] = members[j + 1], members[j]


#Here is the output for the first code:

Enter a name, enter 'done' when finished: Bob
['Bob']
Enter a name, enter 'done' when finished: George
['Bob', 'George']
Enter a name, enter 'done' when finished: Mike
['Bob', 'George', 'Mike']
Enter a name, enter 'done' when finished: Zed
['Bob', 'George', 'Mike', 'Zed']
Enter a name, enter 'done' when finished: Vorp
['Bob', 'George', 'Mike', 'Zed', 'Vorp']
Enter a name, enter 'done' when finished: done
['Bob', 'George', 'Mike', 'Vorp', 'Zed']
```

I created another function for searching the sorted list and this is where I'm stuck. I've attempted to take the sorted list and place it in my `main()` function but it's not printing anything.

```
def main(members):
    name_search = input("Please enter the name you're looking for: ")
    print(name_search)
    begin_index = 0
    end_index = len(members) -1
    
    while begin_index <= end_index:
        midpoint = begin_index + (end_index - begin_index) // 2
        midpoint_value = members[midpoint]
        if midpoint_value == members:
            return midpoint
        elif members < midpoint_value:
            end_index = midpoint - 1

        else:
            begin_index = midpoint + 1
    print(members)

    return None
names()
```

Does anyone mind helping?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same algorithm for regular binary search, simply replace the number list with the name list:

```
def binary(lst, sml, bg, x): 
    if bg >= sml: 
        mid = (bg + sml) // 2
        if lst[mid] == x: 
            return mid 
        elif lst[mid] > x: 
            return binary(lst, sml, mid - 1, x) 
        else: 
            return binary(lst, mid + 1, bg, x) 
    else: 
        return -1
  
lst = ['Bob', 'George', 'Mike', 'Vorp', 'Zed'] 
x = input('Input the name: ')

index = binary(lst, 0, len(lst)-1, x) 
  
if index != -1: 
    print(index) 
else: 
    print("Not in list.")
```

Input:

```
Input the name: Mike
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the `midpoint_value` against the whole list instead of `name_search`. Try with this:

```
    if midpoint_value == name_search:
        return midpoint
    elif name_search  < midpoint_value:
        end_index = midpoint - 1
    else:
        begin_index = midpoint + 1
```

Also for your future questions, make sure you provide a  minimal reproducible example, e.g.:

```
def search(name_search, members):

    begin_index = 0
    end_index = len(members) -1
    
    while begin_index <= end_index:
        midpoint = begin_index + (end_index - begin_index) // 2
        midpoint_value = members[midpoint]
        if midpoint_value == name_search :
            return midpoint
        elif name_search  < midpoint_value:
            end_index = midpoint - 1
        else:
            begin_index = midpoint + 1
    
    return None

members = ['Bob', 'George', 'Mike', 'Vorp', 'Zed']
name_search = 'George'

print(search(name_search, members))
```